# Android: how to display overlay screen over locked screen

Tags: android, flutter

I am using [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) in order to trigger an alarm.
When the alarm triggers, I use [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to show a notification with full screen intent, then I use [flutter_overlay_window](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window) to open the overlay screen.

The problem is that the full screen intent notification opens the application, not the overlay. Once the screen is unlocked, the overlay is visible.

How can I make the overlay be shown over a locked screen?